# Retrieve user's cell/mobile number (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios6

Is it possible to retrieve the user's cell/mobile number directly from the user's phone?

If so, will this number always be valid? (will be able to determine it is the user's actual cell/mobile number)

---

**:( seems like its not possible.**

Answer (score 1):

Not programmatically. This is sort of seriously against user privacy constraints! But if your application wants this legitimately, you can always ask the user for it it directly.